# Map child refs into parent array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I attempting to map an array of children but to assign a ref to them as I do it so I can track their positions from in the parent.

However, I need to store each ref in an array.

I've attempted the below, but I get a **ref containing an array**.
How could I modify it to get an **array of refs**?

This is so that I can track the element positions using a `getBoundingClientRect()` hook

```
export default function ({ children }) => {
  const itemsRef = useRef([]);

  console.log(itemsRef);
  // returns a ref containing an array
  // {current: Array(5)}
  
  // How could I modify what I am doing 
  // to to instead return an array of refs?
  // something like:
  // [{current: HTMLDivElement}, {current: HTMLDivElement}, .....]
  
  return (
    <>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
          ref: (ref) => (
            <Item ref={(itemsRef.current[index] = ref)} key={index}>
              {child}
            </Item>
          )
        })
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: [Read this](https://mattclaffey.medium.com/adding-react-refs-to-an-array-of-items-96e9a12ab40c)  Storing an array of elements using the useRef hook

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy

Here is an example how I would do it.

```js
export default function({children} : {children: React.ReactNode[]}) => {
  const itemsRef = useRef([]);

  console.log(itemsRef);

  refLoaded = () => {
    if (itemsRef.current.length == children.length) {
      // all ref are loaded, do you work here
    }
  }

  return (
  <> {
      children.map((child, index) => (
      <Item ref = {(c) => {
              if (c)
                itemsRef.current[index] = c;
            }
            key = {
              index
            }
            onLayout={refLoaded}>
            {child}
            </Item>
          )
        )
      } 
   </>
    );
  };
```

Comment: I think you're answering with React Native in mind. This is just React

Comment: This should work on both, it has nothing to do with only react native. its typescript and react

Comment: Maybe onLayout is react native, you could add refLoaded under ref instead

Answer (score 0):

Create the refs first (same size as your array) and pass it to your component. I check the childrenLength because it may change between renders.

```
export default function ({ children }) => {
  const itemsRef = useRef([]);
  const childrenLength = itemsRef;
  
  if (itemsRef.current.length != childrenLength) {
     itemsRef.current = Array(arrLength).fill().map((_, i) => itemsRef.current[i] || createRef());
  } 
  
  return (
    <>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
          ref: (ref) => (
            <Item ref={itemsRef.current[index]} key={index}>
              {child}
            </Item>
          )
        })
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```